# mobile - toggling a div on tap \ scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm trying to build a Share Menu on a mobile page. I want this page to appear when the user taps \ scrolls the screen, and automatically hide it if he didn't tap \ scroll again after 2 seconds.

How can I achieve this with javascript \ jquery?

Thsnk's!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://hammerjs.github.io
Could help You out.

Comment: Thank's! That's a good start.. But I need help also with the javascript itself...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout and clearTimeout.
Init the timeout when you need, and add a check when you want to clear it.

```
var timeOutId = setTimeout(function () {
                        hideWhatYouLike();
                    }, 2000);

if (userTap) {
    clearTimeout(timeOutId);
}
```